# Javascript: Load External JS file inside JS File

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load an external Javascript file from a website to a local js file.. 
i've tried this

```
(function($) {  

  $("head").append('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://URL_TO_SITE/jquery.acornmediaplayer.js"></script>');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.jvideo').acornMediaPlayer();     

  }, 2000);

})(jQuery);
```

but it gives me

> [object Object] has no method acornMediaPlayer

i've also tried $.getScript but it gives me the same result

Comment: Do you get the same error, after removing settimeout

Answer (score 4):

My guess is you did not use [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) correctly.

```
jQuery.getScript( url, success);
```

There is a success callback when it is done. Add the function call in there and do not use the timeout.

```
$.getScript("http://URL_TO_SITE/jquery.acornmediaplayer.js", function(){
    $('.jvideo').acornMediaPlayer();
});
```

Comment: actually i used it that way exactly and the funny thing is.. it's working when i put the script locally and use append to the head

Comment: So you get the same error that acornMediaPlayer is not defined? Or is it the items do not load?

Comment: acornMediaPlayer is not defined?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is since this loads with no error: http://jsfiddle.net/FQX2w/

Answer (score 0):

ok i got the problem.. it suppose to be putted inside $(window).load like this

```
$(window).load(function(){
    (function($) {  

  $("head").append('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://URL_TO_SITE/jquery.acornmediaplayer.js"></script>');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.jvideo').acornMediaPlayer();     

  }, 2000);

})(jQuery);
});
```

voila